# Is there a way in which I can order requests to be executed at a late time?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, trading

To further clarify the question that I asked, is there any way in which I can schedule python requests to an API to be executed at a given API? The solution preferably should work even if my computer is not online or executing the program at the given time. I want to this as I have a trading bot that operates on a minute by minute basis, on a timezone that is 12 hours behind my local time. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Uhm, no. A computer can't compute if it's off, and much less can contact an API if it has no network connection. There may be different variations for waking the computer up automatically at a specific time, but fundamentally it needs to be running and online…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute them on your own computer if it's not turned on, no, so you're going to have to run your code elsewhere. One simple approach would be to run it as an [AWS Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html) (not related to Python's own lambdas), perhaps [scheduled via EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/run-lambda-schedule.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider getting a running instance in the cloud. Basically, it's a bit underpowered computer that can run your python code and perform things based on the schedule you provide.

It might cost you about $1-5 a month to run one.